# Why Google has issues with indexing and caching of Angular-built pages?

Tags: angular, caching, indexing, seo, googlebot

If I understand it correctly, the difference between an usual HTML page and an Angular SPA is the following:

- HTML page: after a user request from browser to server, server delivers a HTML page with content,
- Angular SPA: after a user request from browser to server, server delivers a page with an empty HTML structure. Than AJAX request starts and server delivers a JSON with a page content.

What is the problem for Google with indexing of SPA? Is the problem, that JSON arrives later than Googlebot can wait (~5 seconds)?

Could somebody explain me this issue?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140250/do-search-engines-perform-js-rendering-while-crawling)

Answer (score 1):

In general search engine spiders are simple. they parse the HTML on the page. If they come to a SPA (they don't know it's a SPA) and it has empty content... there's nothing for them to spider.  This is a huge over simplification and also may not be 100% true today though.

Go to any Angular app and view source (not devtools, which is live) and you'll see what (in general) a search engine spider might see.

However, Angular has a solution for this! Angular Universal/SSR (Server Side Rendering)

https://angular.io/guide/ssr

For simple applications with no external data, you can pre-render all the routes so they exist as static HTML pages, which Angular will then use as a starting state when the app hydrates.

For more complex applications you can literally render the Angular pages server-side for SEO (and other) purposes via an Express server.

I have two simple Angular sites that do not require external data and use SSR to prerender all the routes for SEO purposes.  https://lyricconverter.net - go there and view source and you will see everything is there from the start (although it is compressed for file size/speed)